How to retrieve raw data from ElasticSearch without being wrapped in content using elastic-scout-driver-plus?
I'm using the elastic-scout-driver-plus package in my Laravel project to interact with ElasticSearch. I have found multiple methods to retrieve data from ElasticSearch, but I'm facing an issue with getting raw data without it being wrapped in content.
Here are the methods I have tried:
1.hits(): Returns raw results from ElasticSearch.
$results = Comment::searchQuery($query)->execute()->hits();

2 models(): Returns Eloquent models corresponding to the search results from the database.
$models = Comment::searchQuery($query)->execute()->models();

3.documents(): Returns raw documents from ElasticSearch but the data is wrapped in content
$documents = Comment::searchQuery($query)->execute()->documents();

None of these options provide a way to retrieve data from ElasticSearch without it being wrapped in content. Is there a way to get the raw data directly from ElasticSearch using elastic-scout-driver-plus? Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
